# How to find user has opened a new tab in MVC .net? how to differentiate between simple click request and tab request on client /server side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to differentiate between a new tab or new window request and simple request (i.e page opening in the same tab) on server or client side in MVC .net?

actually, we are nor using content placeholders in the layout page. we have div in it and child pages are loaded in it.so child aspx pages don't have Master page specified for them.
so when a new tab is opened for page, our master page is not attached to it, so all look and feel is lost.
now I want to identify a tab request @server side so as to send the required page with layout page.

I tried using Request.refferer to find the presence of master page, but the absolute URI is not always same for Firefox and IE

Current Scenario => 
1) Simple request : controller => Action => returns with Master page

2) Request generated when the user right clicks on the link and opens new tab:
controller=>ActionName => returns view without master page attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HTTP header fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) have a fair amount of information in them, but whether or not the request originated from a *new window* is not included. Based on your question it sounds like you are using a lot of client side code for content retrieval and rendering - [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Assuming that is the case your best bet is looking at the nonstandard HTTP request field `X-Requested-With`:

> mainly used to identify Ajax requests. Most JavaScript frameworks send this header with value of XMLHttpRequest

In ASP.NET MVC you can use the [Request.IsAjaxRequest extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest.aspx) to poke at this field. In this manner if a link is opened in a new window you can return the full page Site.Master and all. When the request is your expected behavior you'll know because it is an Ajax request.

That said, I'd recommend working on the way that you are rendering content and look up information on [progressive enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/).

Comment: thank you, but even if new tab windows is not opened the Requst.IsAjaxRequst returns true becouse each time we are loading data in maindiv in sitemaster page using ajax .

Comment: @amol it sounds like you have a right mess on your hands. :) I'd recommend looking at the tenets of progressive enhancement and refactoring where possible. Also, your question is near unintelligible you'd probably get some more answers if you reworked it.

Comment: got my solution,just observed the urlrefferer of http   request and deferentiated between tab request and simple requst,then for tab requst i have rewritten url so that page is loaded with master page.thank you for your help and  thoughts ..

Comment: @amol no problem. If what I said lead you to the answer go ahead and mark my answer as solving your problem. Otherwise your question will remain unanswered which clutters up Stack Overflow.